# How to disable URL Encode?

Tags: html, urlencode

on my website i am having some urls which have spaces.those spaces are automatically encode by %20.

So how can i disable it?

I want this:

```
e.g: http://domain.com/my name/abc
```

instead of it i am getting

```
http://http://domain.com/my%20name/abc
```

Comment: you can't. Un-encoded space character's aren't valid in URLs.

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in URLs. You **have** to encode them.

Comment: Where exactly do you want those spaces not to be shown? Can you clarify?

Comment: You might compromise by adding an underscore '_' as a space. So you could have `http://domain.com/my_name/abc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt):

> Spaces and control characters in URLs
>   must be escaped for transmission in
>   HTTP, as must other disallowed
>   characters.

So you cannot 'disable' this. As biscuitstack suggested in the comments, use and underscore (_) instead, or even better a hyphen (-).